# Adding nested quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am playing around with jquery's append functions. I am appending quite a chunk of html, it is basically an html button containing an `onclick`  event function.

Sounds confusing ? I know. I have some technical limitations which leave me with this as only option for a day or two.

Anyway, here are some examples:

This doesn't work:

```
$('body').append('<button onclick="(function(){console.log(' + '"Hello World"' + ');}())">BTN1</button>');
```

This works and posts an INT:

```
$('body').append('<button onclick="(function(){console.log(' + "3" + ');}())">BTN2</button>');
```

The problem is in the declaration of the string in the `onclick` quotes. I think it should work, but since it doesn't I am doing something wrong. The question is what.

Comment: If you can add script to add a button, then you can add the button and then also add an event handler for it correctly - not inline.

Comment: Whatever you write inside attribute values must be encoded properly, at the very least `"` -> `&quot;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use double quotes in the attribute value of `onclick`, since the double quote is used for the delimitation of the attribute (`onclick="..."`). Instead use backslash to escape a single quote like this:

```
$('body').append('<button onclick="(function(){console.log(\'Hello World\');}())">BTN1</button>');
```

or alternatively if you want to concatenate the strings:

```
$('body').append('<button onclick="(function(){console.log(' + '\'Hello World\'' + ');}())">BTN1</button>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Nesting multiple languages multiple layers deep is a nightmare to write and maintain. Try to avoid it altogether. Create a DOM object for the button, then bind the JS event handler to it separately.

```
$('body').append(
    $("<button>BTN1</button>").on(
        'click', 
        function () {
            console.log("Hello World");
        }
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use single quotes for the attributes, so that you can keep the double quotes.
Just make sure you escape the inline single quotes in the JS part w/ a backslash

```
$('body').append('<button onclick=\'(function(){console.log(' + '"Hello World"' + ');}())\'>BTN1</button>');
```